# Edit fill in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

I am trying to fill a circle with a hexagonal arrangement of smaller circles in Illustrator. This is easily done by creating a pattern (as pattern have options for hexagonal tessellation) and then filling the circle with this pattern.

However, I want to manually remove all the circles which intersect with the boundary of the containing circle.

I have tried "expanding" the fill of the larger circle in order to be able to individually select the smaller "fill" circles. However, this only allows me to select a unit of tessellation, not the actual circles themselves:

[image]

How would I go about selecting (and deleting) individual circles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When expanding a pattern, each module is a clipping mask inside another clipping mask.

To select the content there are two options, selecting an individual shape or all of them:

- **Menu Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Release**, do this step twice

or

- **Menu Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Edit contents**

[image]

Knowing each module has five circles, the best is expanding all the clipping masks because there will be overlapping shapes.

[image: module]

After releasing the Clipping Masks, to clean up the file deleting all the empty frames, select them with the **Magic Wand** with the options **Fill Color** and **Stroke Weight**:

[image: selecting]